# Prove that the problem of rectilinear picture compression is np-complete

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, np-hardness

I need a demonstration that the rectilinear picture compression is NP-hard, I know that this fact was proven using 3SAT by Masek in 1978 but I can't find the paper.

Comment: 1. define the problem. 2. fix typos

Comment: Tell us what you already know so we can help you better.

Comment: It seems to me that [this new user](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/2914/amlv) is posting a list of homework questions, see [1](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3960/i-am-looking-for-an-efficient-algorithm-to-solve-this-problem), [2](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/prove-that-the-problem-of-rectilinear-picture-compression-is-np-complete), [3](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3960/i-am-looking-for-an-efficient-algorithm-to-solve-this-problem). Voting to close. In addition the questions are not well-written.

Answer (score 16):

I believe the asker is looking for an unpublished manuscript of W.J. Masek entitled "Some NP-complete set covering problems". Apparently, this paper is (in)famous enough in its elusiveness to have made it into one of David Johnson's [NP-completeness columns](http://www2.research.att.com/~dsj/columns/col20.pdf) in 1987:

> Of those ‘‘unpublished manuscripts’’ and ‘‘personal communications’’ that
>   have not yet seen the formal light of day, two in particular stand out. They were
>   both originally cited in [G&J], and between them they seem to have garnered
>   more enquiries than all the others combined, sending me off to the copier repeatedly
>   to fulfill requests. One was the 1978 manuscript ‘‘Some NP-complete
>   set covering problems,’’ by William Masek, who was then at MIT but has since disappeared from the theory community.
>
> That paper contains the NP-completeness proofs for two problems of major
>   importance in circuit and VLSI design. One was MINIMUM DISJUNCTIVE
>   NORMAL FORM ([LO9] in [G&J]) [...] The second, related NP-completeness
>   result was for the problem RECTILINEAR PICTURE COMPRESSION ([SR25] in [G&J]) [...]
>
> Before disappearing, Masek sent me a revised manuscript [28], but as far as I
>   know the paper was never published.

Comment: nice answer. much better than the question !